# Show that $\mathbb E [B_{t} - B_{s} \lvert \mathcal{G}_{s}]=\frac{t-s}{1-s} (B_{1}-B_{s})$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion on $[0,1]$ and further let $0\leq s \leq t \leq 1$ with $\mathcal{G}_{s} = \sigma( B_{r}: 0 \leq r \leq s) \lor \sigma(B_{1})$

Show that $$\mathbb E [B_{t} - B_{s} \lvert \mathcal{G}_{s}]=\frac{t-s}{1-s} (B_{1}-B_{s})$$

**using the properties of Gaussian processes.**

My attempt:

$$\mathbb E [B_{t} - B_{s} \lvert \mathcal{G}_{s}]=\mathbb E [B_{t} -B_{1}+ B_{1}-B_{s} \lvert \mathcal{G}_{s}]=\mathbb E [B_{t} -B_{1}\lvert \mathcal{G}_{s}]+(B_{1}-B_{s})$$

So now how am I supposed to use the fact that the process is Gaussian to compute $\mathbb E [B_{t} -B_{1}\lvert \mathcal{G}_{s}]$?

My remarks: I am confused how the properties of Gaussian random variables help us here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the process
$$
X_t=B_{s+t}-B_s-\frac{t}{1-s}(B_1-B_s),
$$
$0\le t\le 1-s$. Since $X_t$ is independent of $\{B_t:t\in [0,1]\setminus (s,1)\}$ (see, e.g., Lemma 4 [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2021/03/29/brownian-bridges/)),
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[B_{s+t}-B_s\mid\mathcal{G}_s]&=\mathsf{E} X_t+\frac{t}{1-s}(B_1-B_s) \\
&=\frac{t}{1-s}(B_1-B_s).
\end{align}
because $X_t$ is a Brownian bridge with $\mathsf{E} X_t=0$.